# help with stub and mock test, how to use a mock that has to return a value also?

Tags: ruby, rspec

The method I am trying to test is:

```
def self.load_file(file)
  lookup = ''

  if file.extension.include? "abc"
    lookup = file.extension
  else
    lookup = file.last_updated
  end  

  @location = Location.find_by_lookup(lookup)

  @location
end
```

So I need to stub the file so it responds to extension and last_updated calls.
I also need to mock the call to file.last_updated because I want to make sure that if the file extension has 'abc', it doesn't lookup by extension but by 'last_updated'.

How can I test this?

Comment: You say you want to look up by last_updated with the extension is 'abc', but your code does the opposite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow would look something like this (substitute "MyClass" with the actual name of your class):

```
it "should lookup by last_updated for abc files" do
  update_time = Time.now
  # create a location to match this update_time here
  file = double("file")
  file.should_receive(:extension).and_return("abc")
  file.should_receive(:last_update).and_return(update_time)
  MyClass.load_file(file).should == Location.find_by_lookup(update_time)
end

it "should lookup by extension for all other files" do
  # create a location to match the "def" extension here
  file = double("file")
  file.should_receive(:extension).twice.and_return("def")
  file.should_not_receive(:last_update)
  MyClass.load_file(file).should == Location.find_by_lookup("def")
end
```